# What is the most appropriate way to compare c# strings

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

This is simple example, which I used to elaborate my question.

```
private void checkValue(string templateId)
{
    if (templateId == "CASH_CHECK")
    {
        //do somthing
    }
    else if (templateId == "CHECK_RETURN" || templateId == "DEPOSIT_MONEY")
    {
        //do somthing
    }
}
```

You can see in the above example I'm checking the `templateId` value with separate string values. Suppose If I have to do this `templateId` comparison in the whole application and one day `DEPOSIT_MONEY` value will be changed to `DEPOSIT_FOREIGN_MONEY` and I will have to change this value in the whole application. And I also think it steers clear of code readability. therefor I supposed to use `struct` like this.

```
struct Templates
{
    public const string CASH_CHECK = "CASH_CHECK";
    public const string CHECK_RETURN = "CHECK_RETURN";
    public const string DEPOSIT_MONEY = "DEPOSIT_MONEY";
}
```

Then It will use something like this,

```
private static void checkValue(string templateId)
{
    if (templateId == Templates.CASH_CHECK)
    {
        //do somthing
    }
    else if (templateId == Templates.CHECK_RETURN || templateId == Templates.DEPOSIT_MONEY)
    {
        //do somthing
    }
}
```

I just want to know, is this the good approach to handle this? or what is the most appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: Yes, it's  the most appropriate way :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks a lot for your comment, can u please suggest an another approaches if you have an idea. thanks again :)

Comment: Why i should add more if you already provided the best, it would be just confusing. However, if you insist, if you had more strings you could use collections. So `if  (CachCheckTemplates.Contains(templateId)){} else if (DepositeReturnTemplates.Contains(templateId)){}`. Then use the constructor to initialize those collections with your constants. If you even want to reuse this, you could pass this as a `DepositTemplateConfiguration` which contains these collections as properties.

Comment: @TimSchmelter haha that's true, but If there was a side I hadn't seen and if there was something I didn't know, I wanted to know about it. Thanks for your point. that's a good suggestion. :)

Comment: Side note: I'd rather declare it as `static class Templates {...}` since you want to create *instances* of `Templates`, it's just a storage of `const`s

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is it possible to use array inside struct? something like this? `public const string[] CachCheckTemplates = { "CASH_CHECK", "CASH_CHECK1", "CASH_CHECK2" };`  ?

Answer (score 2):

To add, instead of using raw string, better wrap them in a Template type.
Reason: You can do better type checks, rule out invalid/empty values. And you no more deal with strings, except during initialization.

```
//e.g. using record
public record Template(string Value);
```

Then you can do,

```
class Templates
{
    public Template CASH_CHECK { get; } = new Template("CASH_CHECK");
    public Template CHECK_RETURN { get; } = new Template("CHECK_RETURN");
    public Template DEPOSIT_MONEY { get; } = new Template("DEPOSIT_MONEY");
    public Templates(){    }

    private void CheckValue(Template template)
    {
        if (template == CASH_CHECK)
        {
            //do somthing
        }
        else if (template == CHECK_RETURN || template == DEPOSIT_MONEY)
        {
            //do somthing
        }
    }
}
```

Another benefit is that since Template is a Type now, you can introduce additional properties or Behaviours. That way, Your `CheckValue` can be free from conditions,

```
public record Template(string Id, Action Do);

struct Templates
{
    public Templates() { }

    private readonly ISet<Template> _knownTemplates = new HashSet<Template>
    {
        new Template("CASH_CHECK", () => { } /*do something*/),
        new Template("CHECK_RETURN", () => { } /*do something else*/),
        new Template("DEPOSIT_MONEY", () => { } /*do something else*/)
    };

    private void CheckValue(string templateId)
    {
        _knownTemplates.First(t => t.Id == templateId).Do();
    }
}
```

This is just one of the ways how you can remove conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's good to have a central location for strings that will be used for comparisons that can be referenced throughout the code. You're previous approach is often referred to as "magic strings" and are considered to be bad because for a few reasons including:

1. They can be duplicated throughout the code making updates difficult
2. You don't have much context about what they are for (a simple variable name can inform the viewer about what the string relates to)
3. You may happen to use the same string in multiple places for different purposes. If you used a find and replace to update them, intending to update the string for one purpose, you would inadvertently update it everywhere whereas two variables with the same value would allow you update either one independently.

Answer (score 1):

You have `public const` values that can possibly change in the future, that is a **very serious** problem that needs to be fixed before it causes bizzare bugs.

Whenever you are not exactly 100% sure `public const` values will **never ever** change, make them `public static readonly` or `internal const`, but **not** `public const`

Following may occur otherwise:

1. You create a `public const` constant in your assembly
2. Some other assembly references your assembly and uses your constants because they're public
3. That other assembly gets compiled
4. You change your `public const` constants (which you should never do) and recompile your assembly.
5. Now the other assembly still has **the old values before the change** until it is recompiled too! That can cause some bizzare errors. This wouldn't happen if you defined those constants as `public static readonly` (still allowing the other assembly to use them) or `internal const` (making them only be usable in your assembly)

Another thing is, don't use `struct` as a collection of static constants, that is what `static class` is for. It is not really going to cause problems, but it is confusing and hurts to look at.

What I would recommend doing:

Definitely change `Templates` from `struct` to `static class`.

If you really need those constants to be public, make them `public static readonly`. As I said, never make `public const` if you think you could ever change the values.

Otherwise, if you are fine with not having access to them in other assemblies, I recommend making them `internal const` and refactoring any code that uses `if() {...} else if() {...} else ...` to use `switch` instead. That is because if you compare a string using many `switch` `case`s, the compiler will actually [make a hash tree for you](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCphA3oaYzQU6QJYB2ALjFBwIYAbUpA4BnLuRwAGUmJykAvKQBE/FQG4GTTjz5CREcZIwy5WJauCbtjXbwHDREqbLFllKsDZY7uDg2cTMzEUSxUAEx9We30nIxdTNwBWcJhovz1HQ2NXOSRwgDMMu384nMSQgHZwgHMfW1IAeia5GBhSLgALfklOTq6OiJhIAFsABzZBGAiqAGJSWDEAV0EuABpSI0EATy2ODv4wLmWDJMMJ/ig2MSN2MVJR/mHGltJ+Qr0L8avOWtJxrA4GNxsseLNlrpSD0xIMxI0SOxuKQALIACnOYgAlMxWPRfKxGBgag8xAB3NhcMBdRp42mEhnyJQAPlIOHW9IZrDEFkUrKwHIJXMZHlZxEFwuFoRZpBQEsljNSfNIyXlCu5BWVSDV6sYYhq0HyMqqOt1AH0ZdJOaQAL5aIU2wg2oA===) so that the comparison is much much faster.